# How to display selected names as selected in table?

Tags: angularjs

Here using this code i got author name in dropdown..but when i selected another author name and save it cannot be displayed on table.it only shows default author name always.how to handle this?

Code:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="selected.title"/></td>
       <td><select class="form-control" name="myselection" id="myselection" ng-model="data.myselection" multiple>
        <!--select name="singleSelect" id="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect"-->
        <option value="0" selected="selected" >- Select Author -</option> 
        <option ng-repeat="x in authorlist" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.authorname}}</option>
     </select></td>

     <td><input type="text" ng-model="selected.price" /></td>
    <td>
        <button ng-click="saveBook($index)">Save</button>
        <button ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
     </td>
 </script>
```

Comment: try to add some code of yours as well, with the issue

Comment: Please give us sample code to work on...

Comment: I post the full code here..but full code is not visible here..I dont know why

Comment: please use edit.then you can see full code

Comment: You have added just a template. Add sufficient HTML,JS code as well.